# How to retrieve similar tags data from db in phalcon?

Tags: jquery, mysql, tags, phalcon

I'm New in Phalcon. I decided to look at Phalcon php as an alternate php framework to Codeigniter. I'm Implementing a blog with tags. where first of im inserting tags value into a single column into the db. I follow tags plugin example from: https://github.com/mfiels/tagsly/blob/master/index.html
its inserted multiple value into a single column like "php,jquery,asp,html,css".

Now i just retrive the value from db to volt like this way:

```
[controller]

$bloger = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Blogs ORDER BY Blogs.datetime DESC");
$this->view->setVar('blogs', $bloger);

[volt]        

<?php 
$blogTags = array(); 
$blogTags = $bloger->tags;
$tags = explode(',',$blogTags); 
foreach($tags as $taged){ ?>
<a class="tags" href="blog/tag/<?php echo($taged); ?>">
<?php echo($taged); ?> <span>[ 0 ]</span></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Now its link like :`"localhost/demo/blog/tag/php"` or `"localhost/demo/blog/tag/jquery"`
My Question is how could i retrieve each tags related data from db?

I'm trying to query like this :

[Controller]

```
public function tagAction($taged)
{
$tags = Blogs::findBytags($taged);
$tagData = array();
$tagData = explode(',', $tags->tags);
$similar = Blogs::find(["tags LIKE :title:","bind"=> ["title"=>'%'.$tagData.'%'],"order" => "datetime DESC limit 5"]);
$this->view->setVar('tagged', $similar);
$this->view->pick('blog/tagline');
}
```

[Volt]

```
{% for similar in tagged %}
{{tagged.btitle}}
{% endfor %}
```

but its not render as expected. How could i retrieve matching data?

Comment: doing `$tagData = explode(',', $tags->tags);` will result in `$tagData` being in an array format. You won't be able to perform a `like`-search on an array

Comment: So How could i query like that, is there have any another way? i mean each post have multiple tags like "stackoverflow" and its in a single column and row, trying query from array to array and if its match one or more than one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through all your current tags and add them to your query one by one.
During the loop you are also creating your bind elements array.

```
[controller] 
...
$currenttags =  explode(',', $blog->tags);

$query          = Blogs::query();
$bindParameters = [];

for($i = 0; $i < count($currenttags); $i++) {
   $query->orWhere('tags LIKE :tag' . $i . ':');
   $bindParameters['tag' . $i] = '%' . $currenttags[$i] . '%';
}

$query->bind($bindParameters);
$similar = $query->execute();

$this->view->setVar('datas', $similar);
```

Comment: Sir, I just try your example. But its not render anything, blank page, no error! i think your query running without condition i mean my if else statement. in my database tags field value like "Social,Politics,Religion" for row 1 and for row 2 its like "Social,Religion" so how this query work?

Comment: i just try var_dump($similar); its shows : "Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in..." shows offset 2 when its count "social,Politics" and offset 3 when its count "Social,Politics,Religion" and more same as if its count only single one tag then its shows offset 1

Comment: I don't really understand your feedback. What are the errors you are getting? I also see I forgot the add the `%` to the like statement, check my updated answer

Comment: Thanx! Timothy. Really you'r Great ! Now its working properly. mistake was '%'. Thanx Again.

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is when a user visit the detail view of a post i want to show that post related/similar another posts on that page. And similarity mached by its tags, Now i figure out by this way:

```
[controller]    

public function showfullAction($id)
{
$blog = Blogs::findFirstByid($id); 
$this->view->setVar('detail', $blog);
$currenttags =  explode(',',$blog->tags);

I want to make Loop Throw....
$dataCount = count($currenttags);
$tags1 = $currenttags[0];
$tags1 = $currenttags[0];
$tags2 = $currenttags[1];
$tags3 = $currenttags[2];
$tags4 = $currenttags[3];
$tags5 = $currenttags[4];
$tags6 = $currenttags[5];
$tags7 = $currenttags[6];
$tags8 = $currenttags[7];
$tags9 = $currenttags[8];

if($dataCount == '1')
{
$similar = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery("SELECT Blogs.* FROM Blogs WHERE Blogs.tags LIKE '%$tags1%'");
}
elseif($dataCount == '2')
{
$similar = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery("SELECT Blogs.* FROM Blogs WHERE Blogs.tags LIKE '%$tags1%' or Blogs.tags LIKE '%$tags2%'");
}
elseif($dataCount == '3')
{
$similar = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery("SELECT Blogs.* FROM Blogs WHERE Blogs.tags LIKE '%$tags1%' or Blogs.tags LIKE '%$tags2%' or Blogs.tags LIKE '%$tags3%'");
}


 $this->view->setVar('datas', $similar);
```

And so on...

```
[View]

{% for similar in datas %}
{{link_to('blog/showfull/'~similar.id,similar.btitle,'class':'cats')}}  
{% endfor %}
```

Now its working as expected But is there another easy small simple way to do this? Please! Thnx Timothy