# Retrieve related post with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm unable to retrieve similar post data from db with [codeigniter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeIgniter_(framework)). In my [blog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blog), I have a tags field which is keeping data like 'php,mysql,mongo,java,jquery'
I just try to get similar post which is related with current posts tags. But im not getting expected result. and the problem is in my query. Its show only three post and that is 1st, last, and number 3rd one.

```
[CONTROLLER]

public function showpost()
{
    $data = array();            
    $this->load->view('header',$data);      
    $data['post'] = $query->result();
    $data['similar'] = $this->crudModel->getSimilarPost();
    $this->load->view('showfull',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}

[MODEL]

public function getSimilarPost()
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('blogs',array('id' => $this->uri->segment(3)));
    foreach($query->result() as $row){ $tags = $row->tags; }
    $match =  explode(',', $tags);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($match); $i++)
    {
        $this->db->like('tags',$match[$i]); 
        $this->db->from('blogs');
        $sqlQuery = $this->db->get();
    }       
    return $sqlQuery->result();
}

[VIEW]

foreach($similar as $row)
{
    echo($row->btitle.'<br/>');
}
```

Comment: write your queries in model instead controller...

Comment: If i write it in model will it retrieve expected result. is it the only problem you figure?

Comment: @munaz he is saying to follow the standard of **MVC** pattern

Comment: no, its advice as @PathikVejani says

Comment: Update my code but getting same result no improvement.Not getting expected result.

Comment: can you please explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
public function showpost()
{
    $data = array();            
    $this->load->view('header',$data);      
    $data['post'] = $query->result(); // why this line??
    $data['similar'] = $this->crudModel->getSimilarPost();
    $this->load->view('showfull',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}

[MODEL]

public function getSimilarPost()
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('blogs',array('id' => $this->uri->segment(3)));
    foreach($query->result() as $row){ $tags = $row->tags }
    $match =  explode(',', $tags);
    $result = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($match); $i++)
    {
        $this->db->like('tags',$match[$i]); 
        $this->db->from('blogs');
        $sqlQuery = $this->db->get();
        if($sqlQuery->num_rows()>0)
        $result[] = $sqlQuery->result();
    }       
    return $result;
}

[VIEW]

$check = [];
foreach($similar as $row)
{
     foreach($row as $data)
     {
        if(!in_array($data->btitle,$check))
        {
            $check[] = $data->btitle;
            echo $data->btitle.'<br/>';
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanx! so much! sir, its working but have a simple problem. that is its rendering visited post two time. suppose i have 3 post "One", "Two" and "Three" so when i visit post "One" its render "One", "One", "Two", "Three"

Comment: I follow your example and its working for get similar data without that simple render problem. Please! Can you tell me whats the fault?

Comment: didn't understand what you are asking

Comment: Sir, i have 4 post(one,two,three,four) on db. when i visit post one it should render post one,two,three,four if they are related. but its rendering one,two,one,three,four. visited post always rendering two time. whats the wrong? please!

Comment: I want same Query with codeigniter. please visit the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36396598/how-to-retrieve-similar-tags-data-from-db-in-phalcon

Comment: probably its due to your post have multiple tags

Comment: Vinie u r right! it was my another post. can u please help me to make the same query with codeigniter? your query is retrieving similar post but its render each post twice.

Comment: :@Vinie! Great Boss! Thnx So Much! You save me. Now its working perfect! Thanks Again.